# Dialog Boxes in Macros

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to negate the need to click buttons when saving a file with the same name to a folder when using a Macro?  I am saving files with the same name, and every time the dialog box pops up asking "A file named XXXXX.xlsx already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it?" it is necessary to click "yes"  Is there a way that this can be negated? 
I have copied a sample of the Macro below.

```
 Sheets("TAB 1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$BV").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="500710"
 Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Workbooks.Add
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 ChDir "\\SERVER\C\t\Holding"
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
     "\\SERVER\C\t\Holding\500710.xlsx", FileFormat _
     :=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
 ActiveWindow.Close
 Range("A1").Select
 Sheets("Instructions").Select
 Range("A1").Select
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the alerts before you SaveAs. Make sure you turn them back on afterwards.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Your save code goes here
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for that MatthewD, working perfectly

John